Transaction builder JSON upload issue
I'm encountering difficulties while attempting to interact with a contract through a multisig safe.
When I try to upload a JSON via the transaction builder, the interface remains unchanged without displaying any error messages. I've attempted this across multiple browsers (Chrome, Safari on MacOS, and Edge on Windows), all with the same result. I've attached a video demonstrating the issue, along with the error logged in the console.
When attempting to interact with the contract through the ABI, I receive an indication that the contract has no public methods.
It's worth noting that when utilizing other interfaces to interact with the contract using the same JSON, everything functions as expected, returning a list of functions.
Any help would be appreciated!


This seems to be linked to the use of the Transaction Builder, in Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team there, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page. They should be able to help you.
Best, Louis

So, I did that, but they couldn't help me and suggested that I ask here on stack exchange. Thanks for the answer

Could you give me the address of the contract you are trying to interact with? Thanks in advance
